# TDictionary via DataSnap crashes, FComparer is nil

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, datasnap

I have a dictionary crash in the DataSnap client because its FComparer is somehow nil.

Server side code:

```
TColorNames = TDictionary<integer, string>;

function TServerMethods.DictionaryTest: TColorNames;
begin
  result := TColorNames.Create;
  result.Add (1, 'Red');
  result.Add (2, 'Blue');
end;
```

Client side code:

```
procedure TformClientMain.FetchColors;
var
  Colors: TColorNames;
begin
  Colors := easServer.DictionaryTest;
  if Colors.Items[1]<>'Red'
     then ShowMessage('Not red');
end;
```

`Colors.Items[1]` crashes (as well as other functions that need the FComparer). The crash happens in System.Generics.Collections, when the function tries to access the FComparer.

```
function TDictionary<TKey,TValue>.Hash(const Key: TKey): Integer;
```

I do receive all the data in the list, and just looping through it with `for color in Colors.Values do ShowMessage(Color);` works fine.

[image: watch screenshot on client side]

When I create a dictionary instance with TColorNames.Create, on client or server side, the FComparer has a value and these issues do not exist. I placed breakpoints in the dictionary constructor and traced the code during the datasnap call - FComparer always gets a value.

What am I (or Delphi) doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to "What is Delphi doing wrong" is:

DataSnap uses a `TJsonMarshal` and `TJsonUnmarshal` from the unit `Data.DBXJSONReflect`. Upon unmarshalling, an instance of a `TDictionary<X,Y>` is created by calling the parameterless constructor. The parameterless constructor here is the one inherited straight from `TObject`.

When *you*, however, type `TDictionary<X, Y>.Create();` you're calling the "correct" constructor with a default parameter (`Create(ACapacity: Integer = 0);`). The `TJsonUnmarshall` class, however, does not since it is looking for a constructor with *really no parameters*. The one you're usually calling has a parameter, even if you don't have to pass it.

I don't know how DataSnap works, but you should probably be able to pass a custom marshal and unmarshaller to whatever does the serialization.

Since Embarcadero closed all the bug reports I know of ([example](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9799)) as "*Works as expected*", it's probably a safe bet that generic collections should not be marshalled back and forth and you should probably revert to arrays.

Here is the minimal code to reproduce:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
    System.Generics.Collections,
    System.JSON,
    Data.DBXJSONReflect;

type
    TColorNames = TDictionary<Integer, String>;

procedure p();

implementation

procedure p();
var
    original: TColorNames;
    marshaller: TJSONMarshal;
    unmarshaller: TJSONUnMarshal;
    asJson: TJsonValue;
    marshalledBack: TColorNames;
begin
    original := TColorNames.Create();

    marshaller := TJsonMarshal.Create();
    asJson := marshaller.Marshal(original);

    unmarshaller := TJSONUnMarshal.Create();
    marshalledBack := unmarshaller.Unmarshal(asJson) as TColorNames;

    marshalledBack.Add(0, ''); // << will crash because FComparer is nil
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense that unmrashalling has to use a constructor without parameters. I think the best solution is to inherit the dictionary class and add my own constructor without parameters. I just tested that and it works nicely.